# How to create a dzi file for seadragon?

Tags: silverlight

I am using deep zoom composer and on the documentation, they said that we could create dzi files. I was following the steps, but unfortunately, i was not able to create any dzi file...

Here's the link: 
http://www.seadragon.com/developer/creating-content/deep-zoom-composer/

Are there any other ways to create seadragon's dzi file?

Comment: What's the problem with ordinary way?

Comment: What's the error? Why are unable to do so?

Comment: there is no .dzi file produced guys... =( I was able to preview, but it was using a .xap file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you succeeded -- the dzc_output.xml file *is* the DZI file!

We mention on our [file formats](http://seadragon.com/developer/creating-content/file-formats/) page that "[the] DZI file may have either a .xml or .dzi extension, as the .xml extension is more compatible with web server requirements." So by default, Deep Zoom Composer gives the DZI file the ".xml" extension.

Sorry that this wasn't more clear -- we've taken this as feedback.

Btw, I encourage you to post any other questions on our [Get Satisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/livelabs/products/livelabs_seadragon_ajax/) page, which we monitor more frequently.